# Git show only the message for the latest commit of a specific file in a branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the commit message for a the latest commit in a specific branch that touches a specific file.

Given branch B and file F, I thought this would work:

```
git show --pretty=format:%b B:F
```

But this ignores the %b format and just displays the contents of file F.

I replaced "show" with "log", but then it displays nothing.

I know I can do this:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%b SHA
```

But that requires a SHA, and I don't know how to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search, as you state in your first sentence,

> « the commit message for a the latest commit in a specific branch that touches a specific file »

then

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%b' <branch> -- path/to/file
```

would seem the way to go.

Then, as suggested by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915006/git-show-only-the-message-for-the-latest-commit-of-a-specific-file-in-a-branch/54915128#comment96596633_54915128), you might consider using the full commit message (`%B`) rather than body (`%b`) alone. Indeed, if the commit only has a one line message (for example if you do just `git commit -m "short message"`), `%s` (subject) contains it and `%b` is empty.

Comment: Use branch `B` and show the entire commit message: `git log -1 --format=%B B -- F` (the OP asked about branch `B` and file `F`).

Comment: @phd Hey that's right, I've answered too quickly, thanks for the improvement! However, is it necessary to specify the branch if you're currently on it?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to get the information for a branch that is NOT the current branch.  That is the crux of my question.  I know I can just do "git checkout B" first, but I can't check out any files.

Comment: @TimurTabi Oh, ok, I edit to take that into account.

Comment: Ok, I just discovered that "git log -1 --pretty=format:'%b' <branch> -- path/to/file" does work, but I need to be in the root of the git tree for it to work.  That was why I couldn't figure it out myself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This script will print out for you all the branches (remote due to the `-a` flag) along with the last commit date, user and message

```
git fetch --all && 
    for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`; 
        do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr [%s]" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; 
    done | sort -r
```